# Инструмены для создания миграций БД MySQL

Tags: php, миграция, mysql

Привет всем! Когда Я писал проект на python/django, там было замечательное дополнение [South](http://south.aeracode.org/), которое позволяло на основании файлов моделей проекта, и таблицы баз данных строить файлы миграции, и применять их к БД.

Теперь Я участвую в создании проекта, который пишется на php/Yii, БД - MySQL. Какие средства есть для создания либо сразу .sql файлов миграций, либо каких-то промежуточных файлов, которые непосредственно мигратор сам применяет к БД?

Answer (score 2):

Так в Yii есть миграции - **yiic migrate create**. Подробнее смотрите документацию: [Миграции](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/database.migration).

Comment: Спасибо! Это хороший инструмент, но как теперь на основе его создать sql скрипт?

Comment: А чем не нравится старый добрый способ экспортировать в .sql из phpMyAdmin?

Comment: У нас командный проект, 2 команды, работающие в разных странах над одним проектом. Просто так взять sql dump и залить его на продакшн нельзя :]

А phpmyadmin насколько мне известно не умеет делать sql-ные diff файлы

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую [dbForge Studio](http://www.devart.com/ru/dbforge/mysql/studio/).

В числе прочего, умеет делать сверку схем баз данных и на ее основании генерит скрипт для миграции.

Работает под Windows. Требует .NET Framework 2.0 и выше. Бесплатна для некоммерческого использования.